# Add sub site to search navigation in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, navigation

I am new to Sharepoint and I got an issue to fix in one of the existing site.

The site has search driven navigation instead of global navigation. The navigation has sub menu under the main menu as below:

[image]

The client created another sub site under Team Sites called ‘HR Toolkit’. They want that to appear in the navigation like ‘Commercial.
I had a look into this and reached at a point where I know that they have a crawled property ‘HideFromTopNavigation’ which is hiding or showing the sites in the navigation. They have below query in the Js file for the search driven navigation:

https://abc.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27contentClass=%22STS_Web%22%20-WebTemplate:APP%20-HideFromTopNavigation:1%20+path:https://lochardenergy.sharepoint.com%27&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=300&sortlist=%27TopNavigationOrder:ascending%27

But I am not able to get where this property is being set for each site, I mean where it has different value or where I can set its value for HR Toolkit site to make it appear in the Navigation.

I could be wrong in my investigation and may be looking for something wrong being not skilled in Sharepoint.
May you please have a look into this and if can help me in sorting this out. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the client add a new sub site, but the search-driven navigation doesn’t update to add this sub site?

In this case, since the search-driven navigation has Security-trimmed and Automatically updates as sites are added feature, check if you have the relevant permission to this sub site though site settings->site permissions.

Check the article to get more information: [Navigation options for SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/navigation-options-for-sharepoint-online-adb92b80-b342-4ecb-99a1-da2a2b4782eb)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, client has added the new sub site but search driven navigation is not showing that. May you please explain in detail which settings I need to check? I tired going to through each and every site setting, I am not getting which setting is making the difference.